# Unable to overwrite method in the subclass because of the undesirably matched type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, superclass

I have 3 classes. I want to have output "want MyClass" for both `myObjStr` and `myObjInt`.

Therefore, I only want the method of the subclass, and I would like to replace the superclass method completely.

But currently, I only got "want MyClass" for `myObjStr`.

For `myObjInt`, I mistakenly got "hate MySuperClass" as output (since `K` unluckily matched `int` in that case).

Is it possible to do the fix if I am not allowed to modify `MyMethod` of `MySuperClass`? `MySuperClass` is from a standard library so I shouldn't modify it.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyClass<String, String> myObjStr = new MyClass<String, String>();
        myObjStr.myMethod("a");
    
        MyClass<Integer, String> myObjInt = new MyClass<Integer, String>();
        myObjInt.myMethod(1);
    
    
    }

}
```

**MySuperClass.java**

```
public class MySuperClass {

    public boolean myMethod(int index) {
        System.out.print("hate MySuperClass, ");
        return false;
    }

}
```

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass<K,V> extends MySuperClass {

    public boolean myMethod(K key) {
        System.out.print("want MyClass, ");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super class should also be parametrized with generics:

```
public class MySuperClass<K> {

    public boolean MyMethod(K index) {
        System.out.print("hate MySuperClass, ");
        return false;
    }

}
```

And subclass should extend the super class with the same generic:

```
public class MyClass<K,V> extends MySuperClass<K> {

    @Override
    public boolean MyMethod(K key) {
        System.out.print("want MyClass, ");
        return false;
    }
}
```

The compiler sees you are calling a method called `MyMethod` passing a parameter of type `int` and expecting a `boolean` in return.

If the signature of the superclass was not exactly `boolean MyMethod(int)` (for example if you rename it `MyMethod2`), then the compiler wouldn't get confused and would go to the implementation of the subclass as you are expecting.

However, in this case the signatures are ambiguous and the compiler takes the superclass instead of the subclass for a "better" match of signature.

> NIT: the methods names should start with small letter, hence `myMethod` instead of `MyMethod`, following the Java standard conventions.

---

If you cannot modify `MySuperClass` to be parameterized, then you will have to explicitly override the super method in your derived class:

```
public class MyClass<K,V> extends MySuperClass {

    public boolean MyMethod(K key) {
        System.out.print("want MyClass, ");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean MyMethod(int index) {
        //Your derived class logic here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to do the fix if I am not allowed to modify `MyMethod` of `MySuperClass`? That is from a standard library so I can't modify it.

Comment: @H42 it's a bit more redundant but you can. Added the example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have some sub-method `public void mySubMethod(K key) { /** something */ }` to be called. In `myMethod(K key)` I can just simply call `mySubMethod(key)` so it's fine. But in `myMethod(int index)`, I need to do `K indexK = (K) index;` and `mySubMethod(indexK);`, which doesn't work. Error message told me I "cannot cast from int to K". Is there a way that I can do "if K is int, then do casting and call sub-method; if no, do nothing"?

Comment: @H42 your last comment is indeed a separate question (which you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62985630/3111149). Please refer to my answer there for that problematic, and stick to the answer above for the Override issue.