# How to do if-else for some specific generic type?

Tags: java, generics, casting, polymorphism, generic-programming

I have `MyClass` and I want to call both `mySubMethod(key)` and `mySubMethod2(key)` for integer, but only call `mySubMethod2(key)` for non-integer.

I tried below codes but doesn't work. I also tried to change `K == int` to something else, e.g. `K == Integer`, `K.equals(int)` and `K.equals(Integer)` etc., but all of them don't work. How Can I fix it? Thanks.

```
public class MyClass<K,V> {

    public boolean myMethod(K key) {
        if (K == int) {
            mySubMethod(key);
        }else {
            // do nothing
        }
        mySubMethod2(key);
        return false;
    }

    public void mySubMethod(K key) {
        /** something */ 
    }

    public void mySubMethod2(K key) {
        /** something */ 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the keyword `instanceof`:

```
if (key instanceof Integer) {
    //...
}
```

Also, you can remove the empty `else` statement and just use an if statement :

```
if (key instanceof Integer) {
    mySubMethod(key);
}
```

Comment: The ternary operator `... ? ... : ...` won't work in this case since the two methods are `void`.

Comment: @Jesper you are right, I had seen the method was returning a `boolean` so I thought it was the same for the 2 methods. Fixed in my answer, thanks for spotting it