# How to cast integer to some generic type?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I have a class `MyClass` and its super-class `MySuperClass`.

`MySuperClass` is from a standard library, so its codes cannot be changed.

As per the user requirement, the method name `myMethod()` of `MyClass` cannot be changed as well.

Unluckily, the same name `MyClass` is already in `MySuperClass`, and those codes are not what I want. I used `@Override` to override those codes (Thanks for [the help from Matteo NNZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62974290/unable-to-overwrite-method-in-the-subclass-because-of-the-undesirably-matched-ty) who suggested me for this fix in the case of having various generic types).

However, I need to cast `keyInt` to type `K` such that I can call the `mySubMethod()`. Below is my code:

**MyClass**

```
public class MyClass<K,V> extends MySuperClass {

    // the name "myMethod" are not allowed to be modified
    public boolean myMethod(K key) { // if key is NOT integer, Main.java will call this method
        mySubMethod(key);
        return false;
    }

    @Override // This is a fix; To Override myMethod(int index) of MySuperClass. 
    public boolean myMethod(int keyInt) { // if key is integer, Main.java will call this method
        K key = (K) keyInt; // <-- I have error here
        mySubMethod(key);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean mySubMethod(K key) {
        System.out.println("I want to call this");
        return false;
    }

}
```

**MySuperClass**

```
public class MySuperClass { // codes of MySuperClass are not allowed to be modified

    public boolean myMethod(int index) {
        System.out.print("Shouldn't be called.");
        return false;
    }

}
```

To call `MyClass`, in `Main.java` I will create new instances for either `MyClass<Integer, String>` or `MyClass<String, String>`. But currently I got error message "Cannot cast from int to K".

I tried to fix the error by using `if(key instanceof Integer){ /** blahblahblah */}`, but it doesn't work since `KeyInt` is already an integer when the method is called. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could do `(K) (Integer) keyInt`, but are you sure that's what you want? This doesn't seem like great design.

Comment: @user, At first glance, it seems that it solved my problem. But can you elaborate more regarding what this code is really doing? Or is there any specific name for this approach? I need to look up for further references to determine whether it will create some unexpected error in my actual problem. Thanks!

Comment: Casting an `int` to an `Integer` is like doing `Integer.valueOf(keyInt)`. `Integer`s are objects, so then you can cast it to a `K`. You can't directly cast because `int` is a primitive and `K`s are objects

Comment: If you call myMethod() with an Integer object it will favor that method over the primitive one.  But I am not exactly certain what you want to do.

Comment: What it comes down to is:  MySuperClass expects ints, and you want to create a subclass that handles any class, not just ints.  Before attempting a solution in code, we must first determine how MyClass wants to handle non-int values.  (Also, since your only expected key types are int and String, I don’t think generics are a good fit here;  method overloading seems like a better choice.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this result?

```
public class MyClass<K,V> extends MySuperClass {

        // the name "myMethod" are not allowed to be modified
        public boolean myMethod(K key) { // if key is NOT integer, Main.java will call this method
            mySubMethod(key);
            return false;
        }

        @Override // This is a fix; To Override myMethod(int index) of MySuperClass. 
        public boolean myMethod(int keyInt) { // if key is integer, Main.java will call this method
//            K key = (K) keyInt; // <-- I have error here
            mySubMethod(keyInt);
            return false;
        }

        public <T> boolean mySubMethod(T key) {
            System.out.println("I want to call this");
            return false;
        }

    }
```